# Change custom attribute based on top position

Tags: jquery

I want to change a custom attribute based on the top position of the element..

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="class" customAttribute="2" top="600"></div>
 <div class="class" customAttribute="1" top="500"></div>
 <div class="class" customAttribute="4" top="200"></div>
 <div class="class" customAttribute="3" top="400"></div>
 <div class="class" customAttribute="6" top="300"></div>
 <div class="class" customAttribute="5" top="100"></div>
</div>
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

var firstChild = // gets the customAttribute of the child with the lowest position top value;

    $('.wrapper:nth-child( firstchild )').attr('customAttribute', i );
}
```

Also, there will be more than 6 divs in the end so it needs to be procedural. thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using real custom data attributes? `data-`

Comment: This isn't the actual attribute, It's just an example without the data-.

Comment: Sort it based on `top` then set the `customAttribute`, what have you tried specifically?

Comment: So how would I go about sorting the position? Thats what I'm asking. Thanks. @beautifulcoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will adjust the customattribute like you've requested:

```
var obj_arr = [];//We will push objects into this array and sort them
var div_obj_arr = $('.wrapper > div');

//iterate through div_obj_arr 
div_obj_arr.each(function(i){

    //Push an object into "obj_arr"
    obj_arr.push({
        idx:i,//pre-sorted index of the html elements
        top:$(this).attr('top')//"top" attribute values
    })
})

//sort the object array
//this ".sort(" will iterate through "obj_arr" 
//and sort them based on the "top" value
obj_arr = obj_arr.sort(function(a,b){return a.top < b.top ? -1 : 1});

//iterate through the newly sorted array of objects
//and assigns the new attribute values
$.each(obj_arr,function(i){
    divs.eq(this.idx).attr('customattribute',i);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should comment the code a bit more, or basically explain what you do

Comment: You're absolutely right! Better commenting shall be my new years resolution. :)

Comment: Wow. That's verbose. :)

Comment: @sodawillow Then I'll hone my balance between brevity and clarity. 
Are my latest revisions appropriately concise? 

Be hyper-critical of my commenting.  Your input is appreciated :)